# Does import create a new copy of imported library?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm using webpack + vue-loader to create vuejs app. I have multiple `.vue` files for components. When I write something like this:

`import _ from 'lodash'`

inside the `script` part of `ComponentA.vue` and `ComponentB.vue`, does this create two separate copies of lodash or does it simply import a reference?

Comment: If the identifier `lodash` points to the same module from both locations where you use it, then yes that module is only instantiated only once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Importing any part of an ES6 module (default or named exports)  produces an *immutable binding*.

> CommonJS modules export values, while **ES6 modules export immutable bindings**. This blog post explains what that means.

[ Source: [ES6 Module Exports](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) ]

So the answer is no, it does not create a copy of the exports. The module is initialised once and each import will receive a reference to the same value.

Comment: And just to prevent any misunderstandings, using `require()` also won't result in any duplication. subsequent `require`'s of the same module also get replaced with a reference to the same value