# How to create an instance of HighCharts in React?

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts

I want to make all/some charts in my React project to use a different instance of Highcharts. I will be [extending](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) some functions in some of the charts, but I don't want the extension to affect all charts, so I would like to use a different Highcharts extension for these charts.

**How can I do that?**

I'm using `highcharts` and `highcharts-react-official` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest option seems to be adding a simple `if` check and run modification only if it is related to a specific chart/series. For example:

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.line.prototype, "getColor", function (proceed) {
    if (this.options.id !== "seriesOne") {
      return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
    this.color = "red";
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-u2j3km?file=/Chart1.jsx

You can also [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057918/how-to-import-as-a-new-copy-of-object) an imported Highcharts object or [use aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm) to install and import two different instances, but it seems to be overkill.